# how to free allocated memory inside a function by passing correct pointer to free()

Tags: c, memory-management

In function "create_memory_pool" I can allocate pools of memory but I am not sure how can I free it from main program.

I think I am missing how to pass correct pointer from function to free by which I can free the memory allocated previously.

Note i can not change the parameters passed to function create memory pool(not allowed). but can change the content inside the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
   false,
   true
} boolean;

boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size)
{
  name = malloc(size);
  if (name != NULL)
    {
      printf("malloc successful\n");
      return true;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("malloc failed\n");
      return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
  boolean rc;
  char *name;


  // case 2
  rc = create_memory_pool(name, 1024);
  free(name);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim you must adhere to the following prototype

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size);
```

Given this prototype, it is obvious that `create_memory_pool` is not supposed to allocate its own memory, but the caller is obligated to provide a block of memory.

What the `create_memory_pool` does instead, is it creates the necessary book keeping inside the block, that allows it to be used as a memory pool (from which, I suppose, you can allocate smaller fixed-sized blocks, with a different function prototyped in the header.)

```
/**
 * Initialize a memory pool in {@code name}, which has size {@code size}.
 */
boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size)
{
    // the initial bytes of {@code memory_pool} are the header
    struct memory_pool *pool = (struct memory_pool*) name;
    initialize stack pool->stack;
    divide the remainder of the memory block after the header into blocks of size BLOCK_SIZE and add to the stack pool->stack;
}

/**
 * Allocate a block of size {@code BLOCK_SIZE} in the memory pool {@code memory_pool} or return null on failure.
 */
void *alloc_block(char *poolopaque)
{
    struct memory_pool *pool = (struct memory_pool*) poolopaque;
    pop and return a block from pool->stack or return null;
}

/**
 * Return a block of memory into the memory pool.
 */
void free_block(char *poolopaque, void *block)
{
    struct memory_pool *pool = (struct memory_pool*) poolopaque;
    add block to pool->stack
}
```

Comment: if possible can you please show me a rough implementation of "void *alloc_block(char *memory_pool)" (pseudo code will work too).

Answer (score 5):

You function `create_memory_pool` is not exposing any pointer.

You must change it from:

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size)
{
  name = malloc(size);
  if (name != NULL)
    {
      printf("malloc successful\n");
      return true;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("malloc failed\n");
      return false;
    }
}
```

To

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char **name, int size)
{
  *name = malloc(size);
  if (*name != NULL)
    {
      printf("malloc successful\n");
      return true;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("malloc failed\n");
      return false;
    }
}
```

And in your `main`, change the call at case 2 to:

```
rc = create_memory_pool(&name, 1024);
```

Your whole case 1 doesn't make sense at all.

You should review how pointers works.

Comment: Gobbo A. de Oliv The you solution actually works but what if i am not allowed to change the boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size) this the parameters have to be the same. is there any way still to do it?

Comment: @shunya There is no way (or I'm missing something very obvious here). If this is an assigment, you might be misunderstanding the proposal of the function. Why exactly you can't change the parameter `name` of the function?

Comment: Gobbo A. de Oliv basically i am given a header file with function prototypes this is one of them and i can not change the prototypes and have to implement according to header file.

Comment: @shunya Please check your requirements for your implementation. It is very likely it is a misunderstanding of them. If you are on an assigment, ask your teacher or your friends. Or edit your instructions and we may be able to help a little more ;D

Answer (score 1):

Pointers don't work like you think. The name you are passing to `create_memory_pool` is useless. And if you want to return the allocated memory... well, you have to return it.

```
char *create_memory_pool(int size)
{
  char *ptr = malloc(size);
  if (ptr != NULL)
    {
      printf("malloc successful\n");
      return ptr;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("malloc failed\n");
      return NULL;
    }
}
```

But then, this function does little more than calling `malloc`, so you could remove it all together.

Actually, a function can return -sort of- several values, but all but one must use pass-by-pointer arguments:

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char **ptr, int size)
{
    *ptr = malloc(size);
    if (*ptr != NULL)
    {
      printf("malloc successful\n");
      return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Some of your confusion seems to arise from the fact that in C string literals are pointers, and pointers are used to manage dynamic memory. But that doesn't mean that string literals are used to refer to dynamic memory!

Comment: i can not change the parameters or thier type in boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size) function is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @shunya: An assignment? The only solution will be to use a global variable to hold the dynamic memory. But then, if this function is to be called many times with different names, you will have to create some kind of associative container. Out of scope for this kind of questions.